# Use value from Picker to populate list

Tags: arrays, list, swiftui, picker, swiftui-foreach

Can I use value from Picker to populate List in SwiftUI

```
VStack{
    Picker(selection: $selected) {
        ForEach(0..<vm.cars.count, id: \.self){
            Text(vm.cars[$0].make).tag($0)
        }
    }
    List{
        // Populate list with **vm.cars[$0].make** with car models 
    }
}
```

Comment: The *value from Picker* is `selected`

Comment: looks like you select only 1 car from the `Picker` using `selected`. Why do you need a `List` to show only one car.make?

Comment: This is fairly straightforward. What you'll need to do is then create another ForEach loop in your `List{}` inside of that loop you'll iterate over your list of cars, and check `if vm.cars[$0].make == selected { //List that car with model }`. The one problem I'm noticing however is in your picker, are you guaranteeing those values are unique? Using separate arrays?